# Windows 7 CMD: processing folders ignoring those starting with a "."

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, cmd.exe

I want to find a folder whose name starts **fld-**. `FOR` lets me use wildcards:

```
for /D %%f in ("fld-*") do set FOLDER=%%f
```

However, with the following folders:

```
.fld-blah\
fld-blahblah\
afld-blah\
```

it also (somewhat unexpectedly) finds the one starting, "**.**".

I decided to test the first char using the DOS [LEFT](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php#Snippets.LeftString) operator. This doesn't seem to work on `FOR` variables (the `%%F` here), so I need to assign it to a normal variable first. Running the following `.bat` file twice (you'll see why):

```
@echo off 
for /D %%f in ("fld-*") do (
set TEST=%%f
echo f:         %%f
echo TEST:      %TEST%
echo TEST[0,1]: %TEST:~0,1%
echo.
)
```

produces the following output:

```
C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\test>test.bat
f:         fld-blahblah
TEST:
TEST[0,1]: ~0,1

f:         .fld-blah
TEST:
TEST[0,1]: ~0,1


C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\test>test.bat
f:         fld-blahblah
TEST:      .fld-blah
TEST[0,1]: .

f:         .fld-blah
TEST:      .fld-blah
TEST[0,1]: .
```

`TEST` appears only to be assigned after the `FOR` `(...)` group of commands completes.

So. Can anyone tell me:

1. Whether I can make the `for` wildcard ignore folder names that start with a dot?
2. Whether there is syntax I can use to apply the `LEFT` operator to the `for` variable, `%%F`?
3. Whether there is a way I can assign a variable **AND** use it within a `(...)` loop
4. Whether there is some other method I can use to achieve my goal (within DOS, I know I can use Powershell, cygwin, etc.)?

Comment: What exactly is “hidden”? ಠ_ఠ

Comment: I would have used XYplorer (www.xyplorer.com), if I were you, it has a very delicate built-in scripting language. (Just as a suggestion)

Comment: @Synetech Sorry I'm in Linux mode - the "." folder is what I meant (of course it's not hidden in Windows). I'll change the title.

Comment: Ah okay; that completely changes things. I though you were asking [something else](http://superuser.com/questions/392969/). It is strange though because while a leading period would make the folder nameless and consist of only an extension, you hadn’t used any of the `~` switches, so it should still have worked anyway. And yes, delayed-expansion is easy to forget and frustrating when you do. `:-/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Been on this for hours and it's just dawned on me what I needed to Google for.

The answer is to use delayed variable expansion, so the `test.bat` script becomes:

```
@echo off 
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /D %%f in ("fld-*") do (
set TEST=%%f
echo f:         %%f
echo TEST:      !TEST!
echo TEST[0,1]: !TEST:~0,1!
echo.
)
```

and behaves as required:

```
C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\test>test.bat
f:         fld-blahblah"
TEST:      fld-blahblah
TEST[0,1]: f

f:         .fld-blah"
TEST:      .fld-blah
TEST[0,1]: .
```